# Django multiple databases depending on models

Tags: python, django

on my site I have a database of projects and each project corresponds to a physical directory on the machine :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField()
```

In my project creation view I do something like :

```
Project.objects.create(path=p)
os.mkdir(p)
```

Some external non django app creates one **sqlite db** per per project, each project has the same database structure (`{project1.path}/db.sqlite3`, `{project2.path}/db.sqlite3` have the same tables).

I would like to read (and maybe write) from these db using the Django Object Model.

Let's say each sqlite file contains a table `cake` with 2 columns `tastiness, price`. I would like to write a

```
class Cake(models.Model):
    tastiness = models.Charfield()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

Then, I wouldn't do any migrations (the tables would just match) and I could read the db with something like:

```
p = Project.objects.get(id=5)
L = Cake.objects.using(p.path + '/db.sqlite').filter(price__gt=10)
```

I've read the article [on multiple db](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/multi-db/) but that doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Maybe another package than django would do the trick ? I know I could go raw `import sqlite3` but I would't benefit from the django ORM.